# Kerberos to work on my ansible setup Minor code may provide more information', 851968) ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))

Tags: ansible

Been having some issues with setting up kerberos within my lab setup.

Ansible server: Ubuntu
AD server: Win 2016 server
Target server: Win 2016 server

Please note that I can get ansible working with my target server when using local authentication.

What have I done ?

read [Using Ansible on windows with domain user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922521/using-ansible-on-windows-with-domain-user)
https://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2017/01/error-cannot-contact-any-kdc-for-realm-while-getting-initial-credentials/

Here is my inventory server

```
[sqlservers]
myserver.mylab.local ansible_host=192.x.x.x

[sqlservers:vars]
ansible_user = ansible-user@MYLAB.LOCAL
ansible_password = xxxxxx
ansible_connection = winrm
ansible_winrm_transport = kerberos
ansible_port = 5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation = ignore
#ansible_winrm_kinit_cmd = "/opt/VA/uxauth/bin/uxconsole -krb -init"
ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation = true
```

Contents of the krb5.conf file

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = MYLAB.LOCAL
[realms]
        MYLAB.LOCAL = {
                kdc = adservver.mylab.local
                admin_server = adserver.mylab.local
                default_domain = mylab.local
        }
[domain_realm]
        .mylab.local = MYLAB.LOCAL
        mylab.local = MYLAB.LOCAL
```

I get the error message below.

```
fatal: [myserver.mylab.local]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: (('Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), ('Server not found in Kerberos database', -1765328377))", "unreachable": true}
```

To test that I can get a kerberos token, I am able to run the commands below.

```
 kinit -C ansible-user@MYLAB.LOCAL

klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: ansible-user@MYLAB.LOCAL

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
05/21/21 10:50:42  05/21/21 20:50:42  krbtgt/MYLAB.LOCAL@MYLAB.LOCAL
        renew until 05/28/21 10:50:39
```

Comment: Maybe your DNS resolution is not 100% consistent, or you have VIPs and Load Balancers _(which are similar to Man-in-the-Middle attacks for Kerberos)_.

Comment: Read https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/errors.html >> some of that stuff is specific to Hadoop, which hacks on the Java implmentation of Kerberos, but most is not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers, in the end I checked everyting, and it looks like a reboot of the AD server resolved the issue.
Also when specifying the credentials for the playbook to use, the domain name needs to be in capitals. If the domain name is not in uppercase, you get a KDC error.

ansible-user@MYDOMAIN.COM